# How to solve this error "cannot resolve method 'addData(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)'"?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, resolve

I do not know why I can't add `boolean insertData = dbHelper.addData(emailString, nameString,ageString, preferencesString,passwordString)` where the addData keep showing error in the lines of code provided below. I wanted to add the if-else statement there is because I wanted it to make sure during the insert data process, a user has to fill in all the details in order to create an account, but not leaving blanks on any of the fields given for them to fill in. or I need to do it in another way? I'm still a newbie for android studio. Please help me.

```
private void getData() {

    name = "" + Pname.getText().toString().trim();
    age = "" + PAge.getText().toString().trim();
    phone = "" + Pphone.getText().toString().trim();
    preferenceselected = "" + Ppreferenceselected.getText().toString().trim();

    String timeStamp = "" + System.currentTimeMillis();

    long id = dbHelper.insertInfo(
            "" + imageUri,
            "" + name,
            "" + age,
            "" + phone,
           "" + preferenceselected,
            "" + timeStamp,
            "" + timeStamp
    );
    String emailString = Pemail.getText().toString();
    String nameString = Pname.getText().toString();
    String ageString = PAge.getText().toString();
    String preferencesString = Ppreferenceselected.getText().toString();
    String passwordString = Ppassword.getText().toString();

    boolean insertData = dbHelper.addData(emailString, nameString,ageString, preferencesString,passwordString);

    if (insertData == true) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Account Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent goappsetting = new Intent(MainActivity.this,setting.class);
        startActivity(goappsetting);

    }else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please do not leave any blanks or user exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Account Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

this is my MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
private ImageView pImageView;
private EditText Pemail, Pname, PAge, Pphone, Ppassword;
private TextView loginacclink, Ppreferenceselected;
Button createacc, preferencebtn;
ActionBar actionBar;
String[] categories;
boolean[] checkeditems;
ArrayList<Integer> mUserItems = new ArrayList<>();
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
private static final int STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 101;
private static final int IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE = 102;
private static final int IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE = 103;
private String[] cameraPermissions;
private String[] storagePermissions;
private Uri imageUri;
private String name, age, phone;
private String preferenceselected;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // this is the status bar
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("Create Account");
    // this is for the check list
    categories = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.user_categories);
    checkeditems = new boolean[categories.length];
    // this is for the items in the xml file
    pImageView =  findViewById(R.id.personImage);
    Pemail = findViewById(R.id.email);
    Pname = findViewById(R.id.name);
    PAge = findViewById(R.id.age);
    Pphone = findViewById(R.id.phone);
    Ppassword = findViewById(R.id.password);
    createacc = findViewById(R.id.createacc);
    preferencebtn = findViewById(R.id.preferencebtn);
    loginacclink = findViewById(R.id.loginacclink);
    Ppreferenceselected = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.preferenceselected);
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    cameraPermissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
    storagePermissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};





    pImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imagePickDialog();

        }
    });

    preferencebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick (View view){
            AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            mBuilder.setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);
            mBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(categories, checkeditems, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int position, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        if (!mUserItems.contains(position)) {
                            mUserItems.add(position);
                        }
                    } else if (mUserItems.contains(position)) {
                        mUserItems.remove(position);
                    }
                }

            });

            mBuilder.setCancelable(false);
            mBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_label, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                    String item = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < mUserItems.size(); i++) {
                        item = item + categories[mUserItems.get(i)];
                        if (i != mUserItems.size() - 1) {
                            item = item + ",";
                        }
                    }
                    Ppreferenceselected.setText(item);
                }
            });

            mBuilder.setNegativeButton(R.string.dismiss_label, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            });
            mBuilder.setNeutralButton(R.string.clear_all_label, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < checkeditems.length; i++) {
                        checkeditems[i] = false;
                        mUserItems.clear();
                        Ppreferenceselected.setText("");
                    }
                }
            });
            AlertDialog mDialog = mBuilder.create();
            mDialog.show();

        }
    });


    loginacclink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, login.class);
            startActivity(intent);        }
    });



    createacc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // insert data into db
            getData();

        }
    });
}

private void getData() {

    name = "" + Pname.getText().toString().trim();
    age = "" + PAge.getText().toString().trim();
    phone = "" + Pphone.getText().toString().trim();
    preferenceselected = "" + Ppreferenceselected.getText().toString().trim();

    String timeStamp = "" + System.currentTimeMillis();

    long id = dbHelper.insertInfo(
            "" + imageUri,
            "" + name,
            "" + age,
            "" + phone,
           "" + preferenceselected,
            "" + timeStamp,
            "" + timeStamp
    );
    String emailString = Pemail.getText().toString();
    String nameString = Pname.getText().toString();
    String ageString = PAge.getText().toString();
    String preferencesString = Ppreferenceselected.getText().toString();
    String passwordString = Ppassword.getText().toString();

    boolean insertData = dbHelper.addData(emailString, nameString,ageString, preferencesString,passwordString);

    if (insertData == true) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Account Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent goappsetting = new Intent(MainActivity.this,setting.class);
        startActivity(goappsetting);

    }else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please do not leave any blanks or user exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Account Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}



private void imagePickDialog() {

    String[] options = {"Camera", "Gallery"};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Pick Image From");

    builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            if (which == 0) {
                if (!checkCameraPermission()) {
                    requestCameraPermission();
                }
                else {
                    pickFromCamera();
                }
            }
            else if (which == 1) {
                if (!checkStoragePermission()) {
                    requestStoragePermission();
                }
                else {
                    pickFromGallery();
                }
            }

        }
    });

    builder.create().show();
}

private boolean checkCameraPermission() {

    boolean result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

    boolean result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

    return result && result1;
}

private void requestCameraPermission() {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, cameraPermissions, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
}
private void pickFromGallery() {

    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE);
}

private void pickFromCamera() {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "Image title");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Image description");

    imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE);

}

private boolean checkStoragePermission() {

    boolean result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

    return result;
}

private void requestStoragePermission() {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, storagePermissions, STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    switch (requestCode) {

        case CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE: {

            if (grantResults.length>0) {

                boolean cameraAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                boolean storageAccepted = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                if (cameraAccepted && storageAccepted) {
                    pickFromCamera();
                }

                else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Camera permission required!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

        }
        break;
        case STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE:{

            if (grantResults.length>0) {

                boolean storageAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                if (storageAccepted) {
                    pickFromGallery();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Storage permission required!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }
        break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE) {

            CropImage.activity(data.getData())
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                    .start(this);
        }

        else if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE) {

            CropImage.activity(imageUri)
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                    .start(this);
        }

        else if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {

            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
                imageUri = resultUri;
                pImageView.setImageURI(resultUri);
            }

            else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {

                Exception error = result.getError();
                Toast.makeText(this, ""+error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```

This is my DatabaseHelper.Java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public DatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
    super(context, constants.DB_NAME, null, constants.DB_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL(constants.CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + constants.TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public long insertInfo(String image, String name, String age, String phone, String preference, String addTimeStamp, String updateTimeStamp) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(constants.C_NAME, name);
    values.put(constants.C_AGE, age);
    values.put(constants.C_PHONE, phone);
    values.put(constants.C_PREFERENCES, preference);
    values.put(constants.C_IMAGE, image);
    values.put(constants.C_Add_TIMESTAMP, addTimeStamp);
    values.put(constants.C_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP, updateTimeStamp);

    long id = db.insert(constants.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
    return id;
}

}
```

This is constance.Java

```
public class constants {
    public static final String DB_NAME = "MMTA_DB";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "USER_TABLE";



    public static final String C_EMAIL = "EMAIL";
    public static final String C_NAME = "NAME";
    public static final String C_AGE = "AGE";
    public static final String C_PHONE = "PHONE";
    public static final String C_PASSWORD = "PASSWORD";
    public static final String C_PREFERENCES = "PREFERENCES";
    public static final String C_IMAGE = "IMAGE";
    public static final String C_Add_TIMESTAMP = "TIMESTAMP";
    public static final String C_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP = "UPDATED_TIMESTAMP";


    public static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + C_EMAIL + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY ,"
            + C_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + C_AGE + " TEXT,"
            + C_PHONE + " TEXT,"
            + C_PASSWORD + " TEXT,"
            + C_PREFERENCES + " TEXT,"
            + C_IMAGE + " TEXT,"
            + C_Add_TIMESTAMP + " TEXT,"
            + C_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP + " TEXT"
            + ");";

}
```

Comment: `addData` missing in DatabaseHelper

Comment: can you enlighten me on how do i add the addData in the Database Helper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `addData(String,String,String,String,String)` is missing from `DatabaseHelper` class. Please add this method in that class.

Update the `DatabaseHelper` class.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public DatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
    super(context, constants.DB_NAME, null, constants.DB_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL(constants.CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + constants.TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public long insertInfo(String image, String name, String age, String phone, String preference, String addTimeStamp, String updateTimeStamp) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(constants.C_NAME, name);
    values.put(constants.C_AGE, age);
    values.put(constants.C_PHONE, phone);
    values.put(constants.C_PREFERENCES, preference);
    values.put(constants.C_IMAGE, image);
    values.put(constants.C_Add_TIMESTAMP, addTimeStamp);
    values.put(constants.C_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP, updateTimeStamp);

    long id = db.insert(constants.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
    return id;
}

//add the method
public boolean addData(String parameter1,String parameter2,String parameter3,String parameter4,String parameter5) {
   // put here your logic
   return false;
}

}
```

Comment: can i know how do i add this method in my DatabaseHelper?

Comment: @yw13 Is this helpful ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. But I seems to have another solution here after adding the method in. I am not able to run the application, but I can now create an account in my application without inserting any data. can you help me with that?

Comment: @yw13 Yeah sure !! tell me

Comment: sorry for the typo in the previous comment, what I mean is I have another **problem** here after adding the method in. The code does not show any error, but I am able to create an account in my application without inserting any data. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @yw13 Raise a different question.